# Unable to save file in node editor using .save filename

Tags: nodejs

I am a newbie to node.js and I have installed node.js version 15 and using linux subsystem(Ubuntu) on Windows. So I have written these lines in the node editor using .editor

```
> function today()
... {
... return new Date();
... }
undefined
>
> function today()
... {
... return new Date();
... }
undefined
>
> function today()
... {
... return new Date();
... }
undefined
```

and trying to save it to file m7.js using the command .save m7.js but i am getting the error as below

```
> .save m7.js
Failed to save: m7.js
```

I have tried adding sudo but facing error as below

```
> sudo .save m7.js
sudo .save m7.js
           ^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Request your kind to help to know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a macbook air and like you I'm a newbie to node.js, also I faced this issue, but I managed to resolved after trying a few options when I realised that there was an error to read repl.history.

despite my efforts, I was still unable to read/save after sudo npm installing repl.history, that is when I realised the solution was to call `sudo` before you access `node`.

```
$ sudo node
```

After keying in your password, paste your following codes.

```
function today(){
   return new Date();
}
function add(x, y){
   return x = y;
}
function random(){
   return Math.random();
}
```

Now try using `.save m7.js` it should indicate `Session saved to: m7.js`.

Good luck